# CSS Style problem in web deployment on heroku

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, git, heroku

Everything works fine, able to deploy the application on the server but the problem is on the website. It shows the content without CSS styles

**Website link:** https://riorana95.herokuapp.com/

On localhost it's working fine. It should look like this:

[image: Scrrenshot of working demo]

Here is my log from Heroku using the command `heroku logs --tail`.

```
2020-07-23T17:48:24.825819+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.143.53.219 - - [23/Jul/2020:17:48:24 +0000] "GET /about_Rio/ HTTP/1.1" 200 882 "http://riorana95.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"
    2020-07-23T17:48:24.827513+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/about_Rio/" host=riorana95.herokuapp.com request_id=4896513b-fe03-43a6-a92e-b001947a1d71 fwd="150.107.10.58" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=1043 protocol=http
    2020-07-23T17:48:25.120451+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.143.53.219 - - [23/Jul/2020:17:48:25 +0000] "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "http://riorana95.herokuapp.com/about_Rio/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"
    2020-07-23T17:48:25.122106+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.css" host=riorana95.herokuapp.com request_id=f70e3d89-e0c6-4dd1-a3c6-e29830608b7d fwd="150.107.10.58" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=400 protocol=http
    2020-07-23T18:23:11.234512+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
    2020-07-23T18:23:11.236726+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
    2020-07-23T18:23:12.219251+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
    2020-07-23T18:23:12.253388+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-23 18:23:12 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
    2020-07-23T18:23:12.253413+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-23 18:23:12 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
    2020-07-23T18:23:12.253414+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-23 18:23:12 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
    2020-07-23T18:23:12.351871+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-23 18:23:12 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
    2020-07-23T18:23:12.438076+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
    2020-07-23T18:23:26.376869+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
    2020-07-23T18:23:26.378668+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
    2020-07-23T18:23:30.025938+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn Website_using_Flask:app`
    2020-07-23T18:23:32.164756+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-23 18:23:32 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
    2020-07-23T18:23:32.165285+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-23 18:23:32 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:50359 (4)
    2020-07-23T18:23:32.165370+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-23 18:23:32 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
    2020-07-23T18:23:32.168764+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-23 18:23:32 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
    2020-07-23T18:23:32.266645+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-23 18:23:32 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
    2020-07-23T18:24:41.561982+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=riorana95.herokuapp.com request_id=4d6522a9-eb49-48de-838e-d51b04f5298a fwd="150.107.10.58" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
    2020-07-23T18:25:10.484012+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=riorana95.herokuapp.com request_id=84e5b587-3a19-42f7-a839-18c52fc8eb7c fwd="150.107.10.58" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
    2020-07-23T18:25:11.936294+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2020-07-23T18:25:13.278599+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.63.41.14 - - [23/Jul/2020:18:25:13 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 707 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"
    2020-07-23T18:25:13.285136+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=riorana95.herokuapp.com request_id=504ebb43-4e09-43f2-a3a1-86152c63649a fwd="150.107.10.58" dyno=web.1 connect=7ms service=20ms status=200 bytes=868 protocol=http
    2020-07-23T18:25:13.345050+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.168.89.215 - - [23/Jul/2020:18:25:13 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 707 "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"
    2020-07-23T18:25:13.346251+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=riorana95.herokuapp.com request_id=a60d391a-6003-47b1-864e-6a4226bf6793 fwd="150.107.10.58" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=868 protocol=https
    2020-07-23T18:25:13.607685+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.css" host=riorana95.herokuapp.com request_id=14b84dab-ed49-4717-8bb8-13c0da850a7e fwd="150.107.10.58" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=400 protocol=http
    2020-07-23T18:25:13.608849+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.63.41.14 - - [23/Jul/2020:18:25:13 +0000] "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "http://riorana95.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"
    2020-07-23T18:25:13.630266+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.168.89.215 - - [23/Jul/2020:18:25:13 +0000] "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://riorana95.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"
    2020-07-23T18:25:13.631668+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.css" host=riorana95.herokuapp.com request_id=87cdf239-1ef3-4948-8251-ec40864570a1 fwd="150.107.10.58" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=400 protocol=https
    2020-07-23T18:25:13.962079+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.93.223.38 - - [23/Jul/2020:18:25:13 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 707 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"
    2020-07-23T18:25:13.964554+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=riorana95.herokuapp.com request_id=a8ddf48a-1f8b-4f9e-8205-af48d1c5a990 fwd="150.107.10.58" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=868 protocol=https
    2020-07-23T18:25:18.042259+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.254.221 - - [23/Jul/2020:18:25:18 +0000] "GET /about_Rio/ HTTP/1.1" 200 882 "http://riorana95.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"
    2020-07-23T18:25:18.043411+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/about_Rio/" host=riorana95.herokuapp.com request_id=cb0d2e0f-63d2-4f5f-b38f-66f1734cd98d fwd="150.107.10.58" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=1043 protocol=http
    2020-07-23T18:25:18.328184+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.254.221 - - [23/Jul/2020:18:25:18 +0000] "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "http://riorana95.herokuapp.com/about_Rio/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"
    2020-07-23T18:25:18.329422+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.css" host=riorana95.herokuapp.com request_id=1b0329e1-39ba-49e4-93a0-e91b555c876e fwd="150.107.10.58" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=400 protocol=http
    2020-07-23T18:25:20.699983+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.254.221 - - [23/Jul/2020:18:25:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 707 "http://riorana95.herokuapp.com/about_Rio/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"
    2020-07-23T18:25:20.701477+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=riorana95.herokuapp.com request_id=1ec0a8a5-e2b3-4767-bb8b-24e92cdef2a7 fwd="150.107.10.58" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=21ms status=200 bytes=868 protocol=http
    2020-07-23T18:25:20.984356+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.254.221 - - [23/Jul/2020:18:25:20 +0000] "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "http://riorana95.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"
    2020-07-23T18:25:20.985628+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.css" host=riorana95.herokuapp.com request_id=6742ee51-f34b-47fd-9775-2e2215546249 fwd="150.107.10.58" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=400 protocol=http
    2020-07-23T18:25:22.816648+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/about_Rio/" host=riorana95.herokuapp.com request_id=66e12c99-eb21-4ff4-9d6f-13ee9a7ed8b5 fwd="150.107.10.58" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=1043 protocol=http
    2020-07-23T18:25:22.817304+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.254.221 - - [23/Jul/2020:18:25:22 +0000] "GET /about_Rio/ HTTP/1.1" 200 882 "http://riorana95.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"
    2020-07-23T18:25:23.107992+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.254.221 - - [23/Jul/2020:18:25:23 +0000] "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "http://riorana95.herokuapp.com/about_Rio/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"
    2020-07-23T18:25:23.109072+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.css" host=riorana95.herokuapp.com request_id=5d0434fb-ea55-4c4b-9510-e8c0e77d152b fwd="150.107.10.58" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=400 protocol=http
    2020-07-23T18:25:25.583074+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.254.221 - - [23/Jul/2020:18:25:25 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 707 "http://riorana95.herokuapp.com/about_Rio/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"
    2020-07-23T18:25:25.584169+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=riorana95.herokuapp.com request_id=25a5fe75-a45e-4ccf-843f-a07bebea1100 fwd="150.107.10.58" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=868 protocol=http
    2020-07-23T18:25:25.875038+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.254.221 - - [23/Jul/2020:18:25:25 +0000] "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "http://riorana95.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"
    2020-07-23T18:25:25.876297+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.css" host=riorana95.herokuapp.com request_id=b06f982f-a952-4fd1-9edb-39ed437a0bf2 fwd="150.107.10.58" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=400 protocol=http
    2020-07-23T18:25:29.179954+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.168.89.215 - - [23/Jul/2020:18:25:29 +0000] "GET /about_Rio/ HTTP/1.1" 200 882 "https://riorana95.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"
    2020-07-23T18:25:29.181088+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/about_Rio/" host=riorana95.herokuapp.com request_id=84d486d8-129f-4142-b654-683560c4e149 fwd="150.107.10.58" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=1043 protocol=https
    2020-07-23T18:25:29.461655+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.168.89.215 - - [23/Jul/2020:18:25:29 +0000] "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://riorana95.herokuapp.com/about_Rio/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"
    2020-07-23T18:25:29.462679+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.css" host=riorana95.herokuapp.com request_id=4019903e-d2ef-4daa-8538-09d0104684c4 fwd="150.107.10.58" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=400 protocol=https
    2020-07-23T18:25:30.253891+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.168.89.215 - - [23/Jul/2020:18:25:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 707 "https://riorana95.herokuapp.com/about_Rio/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"
    2020-07-23T18:25:30.259322+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=riorana95.herokuapp.com request_id=353fc7a6-918e-432b-9057-8630a1a79940 fwd="150.107.10.58" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=868 protocol=https
    2020-07-23T18:25:30.539953+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.168.89.215 - - [23/Jul/2020:18:25:30 +0000] "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://riorana95.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"
    2020-07-23T18:25:30.541893+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.css" host=riorana95.herokuapp.com request_id=fba748ae-7f7a-4086-9add-09dcfafadfea fwd="150.107.10.58" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=400 protocol=https
    2020-07-23T18:25:38.438155+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.47.238.174 - - [23/Jul/2020:18:25:38 +0000] "GET /about_Rio/ HTTP/1.1" 200 882 "http://riorana95.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"
    2020-07-23T18:25:38.440174+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/about_Rio/" host=riorana95.herokuapp.com request_id=38208553-39dc-4f43-b633-2f88d185db06 fwd="150.107.10.58" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=1043 protocol=http
    2020-07-23T18:25:38.746501+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.47.238.174 - - [23/Jul/2020:18:25:38 +0000] "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "http://riorana95.herokuapp.com/about_Rio/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"
    2020-07-23T18:25:38.748666+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.css" host=riorana95.herokuapp.com request_id=9b0a751c-aa94-4acc-8a0c-291ca3bd76b2 fwd="150.107.10.58" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=400 protocol=http
    2020-07-23T18:59:49.123507+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.123.249.13 - - [23/Jul/2020:18:59:49 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 707 "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"
    2020-07-23T18:59:49.128334+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=riorana95.herokuapp.com request_id=b35d8ea9-67c2-4d20-9596-9ea7645006d2 fwd="150.107.10.58" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=868 protocol=https
    2020-07-23T18:59:49.413523+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.123.249.13 - - [23/Jul/2020:18:59:49 +0000] "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://riorana95.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"
    2020-07-23T18:59:49.415132+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.css" host=riorana95.herokuapp.com request_id=e06e61a7-e902-4ef6-9b7e-a76c5ea10ec0 fwd="150.107.10.58" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=400 protocol=https
    2020-07-23T19:31:12.243100+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
    2020-07-23T19:31:12.246818+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
    2020-07-23T19:31:13.399725+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
    2020-07-23T19:31:13.439108+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-23 19:31:13 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
    2020-07-23T19:31:13.444182+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-23 19:31:13 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
    2020-07-23T19:31:13.444188+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-23 19:31:13 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
    2020-07-23T19:31:13.540022+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-23 19:31:13 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
    2020-07-23T19:31:13.776701+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
    2020-07-24T02:46:49.242630+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
    2020-07-24T02:46:49.269496+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
    2020-07-24T02:46:52.708726+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn Website_using_Flask:app`
    2020-07-24T02:46:54.822177+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-24 02:46:54 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
    2020-07-24T02:46:54.822799+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-24 02:46:54 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:19235 (4)
    2020-07-24T02:46:54.822907+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-24 02:46:54 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
    2020-07-24T02:46:54.826995+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-24 02:46:54 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
    2020-07-24T02:46:54.876439+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-24 02:46:54 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
    2020-07-24T02:46:54.991972+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2020-07-24T02:46:56.326724+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.221.122 - - [24/Jul/2020:02:46:56 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 707 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"
    2020-07-24T02:46:56.328923+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=riorana95.herokuapp.com request_id=a93dff84-09a9-4458-90ab-4ef075892499 fwd="150.107.10.58" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=12ms status=200 bytes=868 protocol=https
    2020-07-24T02:46:56.614391+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.221.122 - - [24/Jul/2020:02:46:56 +0000] "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://riorana95.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"
    2020-07-24T02:46:56.616186+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.css" host=riorana95.herokuapp.com request_id=e8f43237-627f-4bc0-a973-8183fc564264 fwd="150.107.10.58" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=400 protocol=https
    2020-07-24T02:46:56.906159+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.221.122 - - [24/Jul/2020:02:46:56 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://riorana95.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"
    2020-07-24T02:46:56.908001+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=riorana95.herokuapp.com request_id=808494d1-8691-43c9-ad3a-a811c4aaafe1 fwd="150.107.10.58" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=404 bytes=400 protocol=https
    2020-07-24T02:49:29.435757+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.41.192.172 - - [24/Jul/2020:02:49:29 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 707 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"
    2020-07-24T02:49:29.438155+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=riorana95.herokuapp.com request_id=0eeeb9b7-6ffb-4ec0-854e-66d988823b12 fwd="150.107.10.58" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=868 protocol=https
    2020-07-24T02:49:29.771077+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.41.192.172 - - [24/Jul/2020:02:49:29 +0000] "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://riorana95.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"
    2020-07-24T02:49:29.773535+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.css" host=riorana95.herokuapp.com request_id=aeaf3464-386b-4375-b17e-7e75a6416c43 fwd="150.107.10.58" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=400 protocol=https
    2020-07-24T03:24:25.677289+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
    2020-07-24T03:24:25.679382+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
    2020-07-24T03:24:28.348363+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
    2020-07-24T03:24:28.397955+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-24 03:24:28 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
    2020-07-24T03:24:28.402535+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-24 03:24:28 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
    2020-07-24T03:24:28.419073+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-24 03:24:28 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
    2020-07-24T03:24:28.520067+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-24 03:24:28 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
    2020-07-24T03:24:28.609430+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
```

**My Python code:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("Journey.html")


@app.route('/about_Rio/')
def about():
    return render_template("About Rio.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**HTML file layout_2 code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Flask App</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static',filename='css/main.css')}}">
</head>
<body>
<header>
<div class="container">
<h1 class="logo">Web App</h1>
<strong><nav>
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="{{url_for('home')}}">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="{{url_for('about')}}">About</a></li>
</ul>
</nav></strong>
</header><div class="container">
{%block content%}
{%endblock%}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**HTML file Journey code:**

```
{%extends "layout_2.html"%}
{%block content%}
<div class="home">
    <h1>Journey</h1>
    <p>About people</p>
</div>
{%endblock%}
```

**HTML file About Rio code:**

```
{%extends "layout_2.html"%}
{%block content%}
<div class="about">
    <h1>
        <center>About Rio</center>
    </h1>
    <ul>
        <li>22-07-2020 :- The longer you live… The more you realize that reality is just made of pain, suffering and
            emptiness</li>
    </ul>
</div>
{%endblock%}
```

**CSS file code:**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #060;
  }
  
  /*
   * Formatting the header area
   */
  
  header {
    background-color: #DFB887;
    height: 35px;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: .9;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  header h1.logo {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float: left;
  }
  
  header h1.logo:hover {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  /*
   * Center the body content
   */
  
  .container {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
  div.home {
    padding: 10px 0 30px 0;
    background-color: #E6E6FA;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
       -moz-border-radius: 6px;
            border-radius: 6px;
  }
  
  div.about {
    padding: 10px 0 30px 0;
    background-color: #E6E6FA;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
       -moz-border-radius: 6px;
            border-radius: 6px;
  }
  
  h2 {
    font-size: 3em;
    margin-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
  }
  
  h3 {
    font-size: 1.7em;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    color: #999;
  }
  
  .menu {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 8px;
  }
  
  .menu li {
    display: inline;
  }
  
  .menu li + li {
    margin-left: 35px;
  }
  
  .menu li a {
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
```

Comment: do you have a file called "static" inside your Flask app ?

Comment: yes, i called folder name as  "website" inside that folder it contain static folder, templates folder, Procfile file, requirements.txt, runtime.txt, Website_using_flask.py, and .git folder

does case sensitive matter in path defining cause folder name inside static is "CSS" and i write in code "css" in small letter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly where was the problem but it working now.

I deleted the app from heroku and .git folder from my "website" folder and change folder name from CSS to css (inside static folder).

then i retry all the process and now it's working fine